# Automation script to SCP from UNIX to Window Server

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sftp, scp

I'm new to server/Unix trying to transfer file between AIX to Windows 
I'm trying to create SCP or SFTP script that will run on cron and transfer text file on `/usr/apps/11.111.1.11.log` file to window folder `D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\myapp`.
I have made secure connection with freeSSHd via PKI authentication method.
So far i have tried:

```
scp /usr/apps/11.111.11.11.log servername@IP:/        <- i left is as / because when I ssh into window server, i set it up so that server root folder is D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\myapp

sftp servername@IP /usr/apps/11.111.11.11.log
```

non of these worked...What did I do wrong?  As far as I know there are correct syntax.

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: Please define "non[sic] of these worked"

Does that mean nothing happened, does that mean there was an error, was a file transferred but incorrectly?